# MongoDB limit find results

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How can I query a collection and limit the returned results. Suppose I have a DB of 500M documents but I only want to search and return the first 10 matches without having to search the whole collection(for performance reasons).

Ideally I could return the nth through mth results in O(m-n) time.

Any ideas if this is possible or how to do it?

Comment: use db.collections.find().skip(n).limit(x) cf https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/js-cursor/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can do that by applying [`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.skip/) and [`limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.limit/):

```
db.collection.find(<query>).limit(<number>).skip(<number>)
```

You can read more about performance issues on [Limit the Number of Query Results to Reduce Network Demand](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/optimize-query-performance-with-indexes-and-projections/#limit-the-number-of-query-results-to-reduce-network-demand)

*Edit*:

[`limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.limit/) and [`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.skip/) can be interchanged, **[`skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/cursor.skip/) is always called first.**

Comment: See the MongoDB Realm documentation for more details on this: https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/actions/collection.find/

Comment: See this medium article for some advice on doing paginated queries with MongoDB: https://medium.com/swlh/mongodb-pagination-fast-consistent-ece2a97070f3