# Limit the results of MongoDB query in query itself

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

It's possible to limit the results of a MongoDB query with the limit function:

[MongoDB limit find results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40356608/mongodb-limit-find-results)

But I am creating an API that you can query by sending a raw `BsonDocument` and the API uses `MongoClient` to find results.

```
public async Task<string> Query(string database, string collection, string qry)
{
    var db = Connection.Client.GetDatabase(database);

    var col = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>(collection);

    var filter = BsonDocument.Parse(qry);

    var result = await col.FindAsync(filter);

    string json = "";

    await result.ForEachAsync(b => json += toJson(b));

    return json;
}
```

But is there a way to limit results in the `BsonDocument` itself? Add a filter maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [`IMongoCollectionExtensions.FindAsync<TDocument> Method (IMongoCollection<TDocument>, Expression<Func<TDocument, Boolean>>, FindOptions<TDocument, TDocument>, CancellationToken)`](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_FindAsync__1_1.htm) method, you can provide the [`FindOption` with `Limit` property](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.3/apidocs/html/P_MongoDB_Driver_FindOptions_2_Limit.htm) to limit the number of returned document(s).

```cs
var result = await col.FindAsync(filter, new FindOptions<BsonDocument>
            {
                Limit = 100 // Number of document(s) to be returned
            });
```